# Getting new BigNumber() error when calling a function in solidity using truffle. How do I fix the error?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, truffle, web3js, distributed-apps

I get this error when I try to call my solidity function using truffle.

[image]

My solidity code is as :

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.14;

contract SimpleDemo {
    function returnNumber () public view returns (uint) {
        return 500;
    }
}
```

The way I'm calling `returnNumber()` is by :

```
this.state.web3.eth.getAccounts((error, accounts) => {
    simpleDemo.deployed().then((instance) => {
        simpleDemoInstance = instance
        // Below line runs with the error ...
        return simpleDemoInstance.returnNumber.call()
    }).then((result) => {
        console.log(result)
    })
})
```

Also, [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47906398/error-new-bignumber-not-a-number-object-object) did not help at all. Hence, I asked separately.

Comment: Seems to me that you're receiving an `[Object object]` instead of the `500` primitive. Is there a reason you're using `.call()` instead of just `returnNumber()`? You could add a `.catch(..)` at the bottom of your promise chain to inspect more.

Comment: Actually I have tried this with `returnNumber()` also, but same error persists. I'll try `catch()` right away now and find if something's off!!

Comment: @IanMacDonald I tried checking for some errors using `catch()` but got an object returned. I have no Idea how an object is being returned. The object is  `{
    "name": "BigNumber Error"
}`. Now what am I suppossed to do with this error. :P

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

`simpleDemoInstance.methods.returnNumber().call({
      from: accounts[0]
    });`

if it is a function that takes gas(assuming you want to send from metamask).

If it is not a payable function you use:

`simpleDemoInstance.methods.returnNumber().call()`

Also use es6.  Trying to write this stuff without async await is terrible IMO.